# gulp Task is not in your gulpfile

Tags: node.js, gulp

new to node.js, trying to use gulp. I got this error:

```
Task 'styles' is not in your gulpfile
```

I see it is a very common error, what can cause it? 
This is my code.

Both auto-prefixer and gulp are in my `package.json` file

the file name is `autoprefixer.js`

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer');


gulp.task('styles',function(){
    return gulp.src('css/style.css')
    .pipe(autoprefixer())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('build'))
});
```

what can be the problem?

Comment: By default gulp uses `gulp.js` module, your task must be there, or you need to _load_ the file with this your task in this module.

Answer (score 0):

I found out my problem... the file name was `autoprefixer.js` and not  `gulpfile.js` as it should be. once I changed the file name everything worked great.